# How to solve 2nd order inhomogeneous differential equation ivp

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am not completely sure if what I am doing here is right. We are given the ivp
$$\ddot{y}+4y=t-2\sin(2t),\text{ }y(\pi)=0,\text{ }\dot{y}(\pi)=1$$
I got the complementary solution as
$$y_c(t)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(2t)$$
I am not sure how to find the particular solution. What I did was split it into two particular solutions, one for $t$ and one for $-2\sin(2t)$. Once I found these I was planning on finding the general solution as
$$y(t)=y_c(t)+y_{p1}(t)+y_{p2}(t)$$
For the particular solution for $t$ I took $y_{p1}=At+B$. I differentiated this twice and compared coefficients. I got that $A=1$ and $B=0$, hence $y_{p1}(t)=t$. I get confused when trying to find $y_{p2}(t)$. I said that
$$y_{p2}=-2(C\cos(2t)+D\sin(2t))$$
Differentiating and substituting into the original yields
$$8C\cos(2t)+8D\sin(2t)+4(-2(C\cos(2t)+D\sin(2t)))=-2\sin(2t)$$
$$0=-2\sin(2t)$$
Do we just say $C=0$, $D=0$? I am generally not sure whether my method is correct at all.

Comment: Can you check the first equation, the left hand side? Is the second term right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your complementary solution has the same form as the term on the right hand side. The particular solution you have tried will not work. What you can do is try $$y_p=Ct\cos(2t)+Dt\sin(2t)$$
Then $$\dot y_p=C\cos(2t)-2Ct\sin(2t)+D\sin(2t)+2Dt\cos(2t)\\\ddot y_p=-4C\sin(2t)-4Ct\cos(2t)+4D\cos(2t)-4Dt\sin(2t)$$
Notice now that $$\ddot y_p+4y_p=-4C\sin(2t)+4D\cos(2t)$$
This does not contain $t\cos(2t)$ or $t\sin(2t)$ terms.